# jQuery Plugin For Custom Facebook Like Button - Fancylike

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe

I have used this plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/social-media/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Facebook-Like-Button-Fancylike.html to make a custom facebook like button. But in vain. This plugin used an iframe to generate the like button. But on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button,  there is no iframe to use. As per as I know the iframe was used previously to generate the button.

My query is that why I couldn’t  set the plugin for the purpose.

Here is my page(first post, heart symbol) where I set the plugin.
http://bdlacne.byethost24.com/Moose/blog1.html

Comment: You should not be using any such plugins to begin with. Changing the layout/style of their official social plugins (apart from what options those explicitly offer) is against Facebook’s policy. And anything that starts to display hidden iframes on top of them is close to click-jacking – so don’t be surprised if this starts triggering Facebook’s security algorithms at any point.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe :). And is there any porblem to use this kind of plugin https://therstyle.com/custom-share-buttons-jquery-sharrre/ ?

Comment: No, those are fine. Facebook offers several ways to trigger sharing, and there is no “trickery” needed to achieve what those plugins do.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot @CBroe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O'my! The problem has been solved :). The plugin works fine with a background image as the hidden iframe sets then over the background. But when I use an icon font, the hidden iframe sets to the right-hand side of the icon. So, at that moment, the effective clickable area sets at the right side of the icon. So, when I attempt to click over the icon, it's not working. But when I click over the hidden iframe, it's working.

If there is any other effective plugin like this, please let me know 